# Mass Email with Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I'm not only new to Rails, but to development in general, so I apologize if this is a basic question. I have an app where I want to send mass emails (ie newsletter) to users that opt-in.  I have two concerns: (1) is my code the most efficient way to process a mass mail (ie do I need to use a for...each statement) and (2) I read other posts on Stack Overflow talking about the importance of the mail server and using delayed jobs to send email.

Other things to note:

- I'm on Heroku
- I was thinking about using SendGrid
- I added delayed job code based on [this tutorial](http://railstips.org/blog/archives/2008/11/19/delayed-gratification-with-rails/)

My questions are:

1. Do most people use delayed jobs even for single recipient emails (ie a user registration confirmation)?
2. Is my code the most efficient way to do a mass email?
3. If, for example, there's 1000 users. Does it make a big difference in resources (ie bandwidth, CPU, etc) if I send everyone the same email with a BCC.  If so, do I just pass in a hash to the mailer (ie delete the for...each and change opt_in_user parameter to @opt_in_users) and change the recipient to bcc?

Thanks!

Controller

```
commmunity_users = UserCommunityRelation.find('community_id = ? and status = ?,'      current_community, "approved" )
@opt_in_users = User.find('opt_in = ?,' true)

@opt_in_users.each do |opt_in_user|
  UserMailer.send_later(:deliver_announcement, opt_in_user)
end
```

UserMailer.rb

```
def announcement(opt_in_user)
  mail(:to => "#{opt_in_user.username} <#{opt_in_user.email}>", :subject => "Huge Announcement!")
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For bulk sending, you should definitely send it via a service (We use Postbox, SendGrid is another option). In addition to the load on the servers, a service will also probably be better suited to bounces, spam blockers, etc, and it will probably offer extra benefits, such as tracking.

> Do most people use delayed jobs even for single recipient emails (ie a user registration confirmation)?

For single user emails, I would go with direct emails in the controller.

> Is my code the most efficient way to do a mass email?

You wouldn't want to have a controller action manage queueing the tasks, as it will affect your sites responsiveness. Use a cron job and rake task to do it in the background.

> If, for example, there's 1000 users. Does it make a big difference in resources (ie bandwidth, CPU, etc) if I send everyone the same email with a BCC. If so, do I just pass in a hash to the mailer (ie delete the for...each and change opt_in_user parameter to @opt_in_users) and change the recipient to bcc?

I think BCC is fine on resource usage, but your server will be getting hit with any bounces, and it is an extra service to manage, hence, I'd go with a service as mentioned earlier

BTW, for the #each vs for...each question, the cost of the iterator is going to be so low that it isn't worth thinking about IMO.

Comment: I would still use SendGrid even for the one-off emails. Better delivery, primarily, analytics secondarily.

Comment: Also you want to use Delayed Job where possible since you are interacting with an external service and you don't know how long it will take to process - let it happen in the background and return control to the user.